# BitLocker I know my Password but not the recovery key

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, windows-10, data-recovery, bitlocker

Yesterday I turned of my long life running Windows machine that uses Bitlocker for years. In the shutdown sequence, Windows installed updates.

Today I started my machine, and as usual, I enter the password for Bitlocker. Then, the machine seems to start for a few seconds and then reboots. This happens now all the time. I can select other options in the Bitlocker to but then I get asked for my recovery key, which I unfortunately can not find. It's not in my windows account.

Is there any way how I can access my data?

Comment: Do you know what mode Bitlocker was configured with, e.g. TPM or other options? Furthermore, yes, there *is* a reason why you're told to store the recovery key. There's also a reason for why backups is a good idea.

Comment: I don't know. I know that I always have to type in my bitlocker password before the bootup of windows 10.

Comment: What you describe is a security feature of BitLocker.  A configuration change must have happened.  Without the the recovery key you will be unable to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have a *disk image* made before the update? You can recover everything from that, if so.

Comment: I have a complete encrypted Backup in the cloud. I will reinstall Windows on a new SSD and get my data from the backup and then i make shure to save the recovery key.

Comment: @swftowu69 -That won’t work. You changing the boot order in order to boot to that backup will cause BitLocker to detect a configuration change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really used a password and not a PIN, then you have full control at any time. If the machine does not boot, that's another story, but the data is yours, no recovery key needed!

So boot windows setup (create a bootable USB stick), and when you arrive at the language selection, press shift and F10 together - a command line will appear. There, launch:

```
manage-bde -unlock c: -pw
```

Now your password will be asked for. If that works, you'll be able to:

```
dir c:
```

and (for example)

```
xcopy c:\users\youruser\documents d:\myusbstickfolder /E /H /C /I
```

(this assumes that setup sees your encrypted system drive as c:)